# Error when creating site collection "Permanently delete the site collection from the recycle bin and continue."

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, administration, recycle-bin

I want to create a new site collection with url `/sites/PMO/`, but I am getting this error:

> The site collection already exists. Please enter a different address.
>
> Permanently delete the site collection from the recycle bin and
>   continue.

As follow:

[image]

But I checked our recycle bin and it does not have any site. Also I checked the modern site collection and none of them have this url `/sites/pmo/`.

So not sure why I am getting this error? and which recycle bin it is refereeing to `Permanently delete the site collection from the recycle bin and continue.` as our recycle bin is empty, as follow:

[image]
[image]

Comment: how long you wait before create new site collection? i mean after deleting from recyclebin, it should be quick but just wondering. what you get when you browse the URL, file not found?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP yes page not found

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP i think 9 months ago i created a site with the same url `sites/pmo/` but i have removed it from from recycle bin at that time.. maybe Microsoft keeps this site somewhere for longer time? that why i am getting a checkbox to permanently delete this site from recycle bin? for example we have an active site "/sites/hr" and when i intentionally tried to create a new site collection with the same url, i will get a message that the site already exists,

Comment: but will not get an checkbox to permeability remove it from recycle bin (as in the `/sites/pmo` case)..so give an indication that the site `/sites/pmo/` is not active??

Comment: I agree, i did the quick test with couple of combinations and every one works as expected. two things you can try, 1st run the powershell get-spodeletedsites and see if it return PMO or try to logout from the tenant and clear browser cache...login back and try agin....lastly you can check that box (permanently)

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP  `Get-SPODeletedSite` will not return anything.. also `Get-SPODeletedSite -IncludePersonalSite ` will return a single personal site with url `https://***-my.sharepoint.com/personal/test_user_**_com`... i tried to logout + clear the cache ,, but still i will get the same error..

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP i check the permanently remove site collection from recycle bin.. and i got a message that it might take up to 24 hours for the site to be created !!!

Comment: Yup that was the other thought i have...may be its time frame ( depending upon your datacenter region, may be Who know), other that you can open the support ticket with MSFT.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP after 5 minutes the site creation process completed and now i can access the site collection... so not sure why Microsoft showed us a message that it can take up to 24 hours for the task to complete then?

Comment: it is their safe statement, in many cases it is just matter of minutes but rare cases it may stuck up. Just think, may be heavy operation is going on in your data-center which throttle the resources.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88811/discussion-between-waqas-sarwar-mvp-and-sharepoint-testdev).

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is timing issue. Some time it will delete the site collection from recycbin quickly or take upto 24 hours. It is depending upon the resource utilization on your tenant / DataCenter. May be MSFT doing the throttling so thats why it take upto 24 hours (typically after 24 hours it clear the throttling limit).

Couple of things, we can try.

- logout from tenant, clear the cache and try again.
- RUN get-spodeletedsites and make sure it is not returning the site
- when creating the new site collection then check the box (permanent delete site collection).
- if issue still there after 24 hours then contact the support.

Comment: for the 24 hours are you talking about the time to delete old site collection? or for creating a new one?

Comment: i am talking about when you remove the site from recycle-bin.

Comment: but i have created the site 6 months ago and i also removed it from recycle bin after that..

Comment: When you delete the site collection (PMO) from recycle bin in new sharepoint admin center? Do you have any information right or retention policy on that site collection

Comment: i removed the site collection from the recycle bin just after creating the site in couple of weeks.. so at-least the site collection was removed from recycle bin 5 months ago !!